# Add arrow css after angular material tab

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular-material tab to display some tabs. I want to add some arrow css after each tab. Below is the code snippet that i'm trying. But not able to display the arrow

```html
<mat-tab-group>
        <mat-tab label="Marketing" *ngIf="isMarketingTaskEnabled()">
            <div class="step-content">
                    <my-task-list [Search]="search" [jobType]="myTaskType.MARKETING" [salesOrders]="salesOrders" [tableData]="tableData[myTaskType.MARKETING]"></my-task-list>
            </div>
        </mat-tab>

        <mat-tab label="Project Management" *ngIf="isProjectManagementEnabled()">
            <my-task-list [Search]="search" [jobType]="myTaskType.PROJECT_MANAGEMENT" [salesOrders]="salesOrders" [tableData]="tableData[myTaskType.PROJECT_MANAGEMENT]"></my-task-list>
        </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group
```

```css
.mat-tab-label.mat-tab-label-active::after{
    content: '';
    display: block;  
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid #3c4650 ;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    left:100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want customized tab titles(Which includes icons, images) instead plain title. Then you need to use **ng-template** with **mat-tab-label** inside mat-tab.
Eg:

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab>
      <ng-template mat-tab-label>
         <mat-icon>home</mat-icon> Home
      </ng-template>
      <p> Tab Content </p>
   </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

For your reference: [Angular Material Tabs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#labels)